# Connecting to windows server from PCF

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I came across a very different requirement today where the Application running in `PCF` has to connect to `Windows-Server` and execute some business logics.

Currently the teams are achieving it using `VB-Script`. The command looks something like this

```vb
Dim computerToConnect As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Server + ",computer")
```

The same functionality the teams are trying to achieve through a `spring-boot` app running in `PCF Linux stack`.

Is there a way to achieve this in `Java` ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question:

> Yes, it is possible to connect into Windows Server from Spring Boot.

You can start from:

> 1. Investigate better what you really need to do inside the Windows Server, to understand how you can translate it in Java/Spring code;
> 2. Investigate what kind of authentication your company use in the Windows Server;
> 3. For example, if your company use LDAP/OpenLDAP, you need to learn how to connect from Spring Boot app into Windows Server using this kind of authentication;
> 4. Configure your Spring Boot app with the credentials to handle the authentication;
> 5. After authenticate, consume the resources you want, similar to VB-Script.